# Opposite term of indent

Tags: terminology

We say that we indent code. I'm writing a string builder which can add/remove tabs to indent code.

Sample:

```
builder.Add("<ul>");
builder.Indent();
builder.Add("<li></li>");
builder.Dedent(); // <-- what should this be named.
builder.Add("</ul>");
```

What should I name the method?

Comment: It's somewhat off topic but : maybe you could avoid explicitly calling indent/dedent if you replaced Add("<ul>") and Ident() calls by a BeginElement("ul") that would include indent logic. (and also a EndElement method of course)

Comment: @David: +1, but of course you'd want to take inline nested elements into account :)

Comment: What about `outdent`?

Comment: @Kevin: Great alternative, but why don't you add it as an answer?

Comment: @David: It's used inside a framework and not exposed to the user (the class is public though so that user can use it for it's own purposes). Also it can be used for more than just markup, so `BeginElement` etc isn't appropriate.

Comment: @jgauffin : being inside a framework does not mean you should not make it easier to use and harder to misuse. By the way, you can have a subclass of your builder dedicated to markup, so that you have the best of both worlds.

Comment: @David: I'm well aware of how I can encapsulate the class or subclass it. I'm just saying that it isn't appropriate in my specific use case.

Comment: Vote to migrate this to http://english.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: What about `builder.Indents.Push ()` and `builder.Indents.Pop ()` ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Out is the opposite of in, everybody knows this. Why not use `Indent()` and `Outdent()`?

Comment: This is what I've always called it at least.

Comment: Same here, I've always heard it called outdent.

Answer (score 17):

```
Indent
Dedent
```

To back up this, a quick google helps:
unindent has 290,000 hits while dedent has 1,920,000 hits, giving a rough indication that the latter one is more widely used. Although this should be used as argument very cautiously.

`Dedent` is also the standart terminology used in the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html).

Comment: +1: Learn something new every day (had *never* heard of the term `dedent` before) - although I'd always advise against it as 90% of people would probably not know what it is (seems to be a spawn of Python).

Comment: In fact "dedent" has only 321,000 hits when you put it in quotes and many of those hits haven't got anything to do with indentation, but are rather names or other things (dentist terms maybe?). "unindent" has 267.000 hits.

Comment: I suspect that the difference in Google hits comes from the popularity of python. For instance the vi terminology is unindent.

Comment: Dedent is not an actual English word. A good API is clear and easily understood by anyone reading the source (as much as I love Python, this introduced me to a quirk that I'm not fond of at all). Next to each other, this makes sense, but might not otherwise (or to someone who is not quite fluent in English).

Comment: @Demian Of course it’s an English word, we’re using it. How could we use it if it didn’t exist? English isn’t a tightly regulated prescriptivist language.

Comment: Well, "outdent" has almost 14 million hits.

Comment: @Demian Brecht: It's just a neologism. As a programmer, you're immersed in them daily. Get used to it.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: I'm quite used to it (been doing this for a while). Still doesn't make it a good idea and doesn't mean that there aren't better alternatives.

Comment: @Konrad: My apologies, I should have been more explicit: It's not a *commonly* used English word for which the definition is clear at a glance, especially when taken out of the poster's context.

Answer (score 17):

For the opposite of `indent`, I would use `unindent`. From Wiktionary:

> [**unindent**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unindent)
>
> **Etymology**
>   un- +‎ indent; Originated in the 1980s when computers made
>   it trivial for anyone to move text around on a page.
>   **Verb**
>   **unindent** (*third-person singular simple present* **unindents**, *present
>   participle* **unindenting**, *simple past and past participle* **unindented**)
>   1. To
>   remove the indentation; to move a block of text closer to the left
>   margin.
>   *I had to **unindent** the first line of each paragraph so that my
>   essay would fit onto one side of paper.*

According to the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=indent), indent comes from:

> early 15c., *indenten/endenten* "to make notches; to give (something) a
>   toothed or jagged appearance," also "to make a legal indenture," from
>   O.Fr. *endenter* "to notch or dent, give a serrated edge to," from M.L.
>   *indentare* "to furnish with teeth," from in- "into, in, on, upon" (see
>   in- (2)) + L. *dens* (gen. *dentis*) "tooth" (see tooth). Related:
>   *Indented; indenting*. The printing sense is first attested 1670s. The
>   noun is first recorded 1590s, from the verb. An earlier noun sense of
>   "a written agreement" (late 15c.) is described in Middle English
>   Dictionary as "scribal abbrev. of *endenture*."

So indenting is like to putting a "notch" in the source code. To remove that notch, you undo the indent: unindent.

Answer (score 12):

Don't you mean [indent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation)?

Intend means something completely different.

Otherwise, maybe `Unindent`?

On a side note:

- Using tabs to indent code is [bad](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/04/death-to-the-space-infidels.html) (imho) - spaces are more portable.
- I wouldn't have this API exposed to the client. The `builder` should be smart enough to know what to and what to not indent.

Comment: The post by Jeff Atwood doesn't say why using tabs is bad. It just throws out an insult to tab-users at the end.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I edited my answer - I thought that was another blog post that I'd read ages ago that spoke ill of using tabs and why.

Comment: related to API exposition, I agree. Implementing a default strategy for formatting the incoming XML (for example +1 space/tab for an opening tag, -1 for a closing tag), and allowing this strategy to be changed by the API user would be nice.

Comment: "spaces are more portable": what the heck should that mean?!?!? ...also, I don't agree tabs are bad, actually, I personally find them *good*. It is cleaner, easier to parse, and enables the user to choose how spacy they should be represented in the view. I don't see any negative downside on them, in contrast to spaces which don't have the previously mentioned advantages.

Comment: @arnaud: you should read up on tabs vs. spaces. it's largely a religious debate, but in my experiences, spaces have always prevailed (*especially* if you're working on an OS project or have multiple developers who use different editors). really, at the end of the day, the important thing is consistency.

Comment: @arnaud (cont'd): portable across multiple editors. might want to read up on that as well.

Comment: The class can be used for more than just markup. It's just as generic as a StringBuilder.

Comment: @jgauffin: Then I might still hide that specific API from the user and maybe add an optional parameter to `Add` to increase the indentation level (using an `enum`, not a `bool` - but that's another conversation altogether ;))

Comment: The best is having an editor which automatically put X spaces when you press Tab.

Comment: @arnaud It’s simple, really: not a single web browser handles tabs in code displays. Therefore, the only way to share readable code fragments via HTML is to use spaces for indentation.

Comment: Tabs are more portable I thought - not all editors have "smart tabs" and it is effort pressing backspace 4 times to outdent once using spaces when only one time will suffice for tabs.

Comment: @Callum Care to name a single, modern, programmer-oriented editor that does *not* support smart tabs?

Comment: @Konrad: Name one editor that does not support tabs?

Comment: @CallumRogers That wasn’t the point, *you* were talking about editors, and you claimed that not all support smart tabbing. And I’ve already named other applications that don’t support tabs: web browsers. Read my comment above.

Comment: We were debating tabs versus spaces already in 1985. Surely i don't care any more because my editor reflows according to my preferences anyway. Same with curly braces. Diff tools will ignore whitespace mostly. Please lets move on to more meaningful topics.

Comment: @RobvanderVeer: This conversation moved on nearly two years ago ;)

Answer (score 6):

The word "indent" doesn't actually mean "insert whitespace" - it means "adjust whitespace so that things line up". As such, indenting can mean both adding or removing tabs; just like there is no opposite to "walk", conceptually speaking there is no opposite to "indent". You can remove indentation, undo the indenting, or change the indentation level, each of which are operations that somehow revert or alter the effects of indenting, in different ways, but none of them is "the" opposite of indenting. The popular "dedent" and "unindent" are wrong the same way as "unwalk" or "defest". (BTW, this might make a good question for english.se)

In your case, I'd go with `IncreaseIndentationLevel` and `DecreaseIndentationLevel`.

Comment: english.se isn't very fond of discussing programming terms.

Comment: It's more a typesetting term than a programming term, but OK.

Comment: "Indention", not "indentation".

Comment: Agreed, "Increase Indent" and "Decrease Indent" are the correct terms, strictly speaking. I would expect that to be language that programmers would use and understand. You do use "negative acceleration" when you talk about bringing your car to a halt, don't you?

Answer (score 5):

What about 
`SetIndentLevel(int level)`.

Removing an indent is then just setting the level to 0. Afaik there's no term for the opposite of this operation.

Comment: +1 - That's a better approach than two function calls to increment & decrement the indent level.

Comment: Not sure it's better than 2 methods. Using a setIndentLevel methods means it's your responsibility to remember how deep indentation has gone in case of nested elements in the document. That would mean keeping a counter. No, definitely that should be builder's responsibility, not yours.

Comment: @David: You can easily create two wrapper methods to keep track of it. In some cases it may be better or easier to use while in other cases its not.  With an other interface you'd have to call an increase/decrease method multiple times or in a loop. So I'd probably want all three versions: Set/Increase/Decrease

Comment: @David `setIndentLevel(1 + getIndentLevel())` - the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen the word "outdent", for example at Wikipedia [Template:Outdent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aOutdent) page

> For outdenting a reply on a talk page when indention gets too deep. Indenting on talk pages is done using a colon character (:) to produce tabs; this template produces a connector bar and initial text to indicate an outdent, based on the number of colons used in the previous indent...

Answer (score 2):

I've seen `Dedent` in Fowler's book on DSLs.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW Google Docs and MS Word uses "Increase Indent" and "Decrease Indent".  I forget which editor (maybe it was TinyMCE, been working with that lately) but I know I once saw "Indent" and "Outdent"

Answer (score 1):

Definition of Indent:

> Start (a line of text) or position (a block of text, table, etc.) further from the margin than the main part of the text

There is not really an opposite of this, rather you are indenting the main text further than the specified line.

I think a better term would be RemoveIndent() or ReduceIndent()

Having said that, a google search for the term "opposite of indent" reveals the following term: **Outdent**. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=indent This may also be suitable.

Comment: Outdent is just as ugly as dedent. The "in-" in "indent" is not a prefix, really, replacing it as if it were is an abuse of English grammar.

Comment: @tdammers - in a sense it is. You are denting the paragraph inwards, so the opposite would be to dent it outwards - Outdent. Personally I prefer Remove/ReduceIndent() though for a function name...

Comment: @tdammers: Apparently the "in-" in *indent* **is** a prefix ("into, in, on, upon" – http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=indent). Not that it matters – I don't see anything "abusive" about folk etymology (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folk_etymology); it's part of language evolution. And I disagree that *outdent* is as ugly as *dedent*. I'm not even sure which syllable to stress in *dedent*; it's very ugly either way. But *outdent* is nice and obvious. It's a perfect complement to *indent*. The two words create a nice pair that define one another with a very visual contrast. I like it.

Comment: Sorry, I've just realised I've failed to read this question or its answers properly... I was assuming it was about the automatic display of wrapped lines in a text editor. In which case, *outdent* (meaning the option of displaying a line *further left* than the line above it) would be perfect in my opinion. But this question is actually about *removing* an indent that already exists – like what happens when you press Shift+Tab. In which case, I agree with `reduceIndent()`, or even `unindent()`.

Comment: Did my own research; yes, the "in-" is actually a prefix, but as callum states, "outdent" would mean a line that starts left of the left edge. IIRC, such a thing is called a negative indent in typesetting, not an outdent, and it's not what we're talking about here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but just had the same problem finding the opposite for `Indent`.
As here are several different answers to that question, I asked an English colleague (UK) what he would choose: His first tip was `IncreaseIndent` and `DecreaseIndent`. But `Indent` and `Detent` would also work.